# save textbox or check values C# WPF .Net VS2008

Tags: c#, wpf, load, settings, save

i have many textbox and check box on my wpf .
how to save entered values as a separate (any format) file , so that values can be loaded when ever required.

thanks

Comment: P.S. default properties ..always gives me last entered values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class with relevant properties in which you store the values, then your elements [can be bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to those properties and the file can be [serialized and deserialized as XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a method to avoid assigning an x:Name to each TextBox or CheckBox and writing a line of code for each.  My suggestion is to assign a Tag string that begins with some constant, such as "$SaveMe$".  Then either concatenate a unique name or assign an x:Name to each.  Your code can then do a single recursion, walking the visual tree and grabbing each TextBox or CheckBox with the indicated tag value and writing it with an XmlWriter.  Similarly you can load it back with an XmlReader when the x:Name or remaining Tag value matches the Xml name.